# About 'grep -f': match pattern with file

Tags: grep

I am using the `grep -f` function to extract lines from a file which match a particular pattern. Let's say my pattern file is `pattern.txt`, as follows.

```
1
2
3
4
5
```

And the file against which I am matching this pattern is `file.txt`,

```
1::anv
2::tyr
3::yui
4::fng
5::gdg
6::ere
7::rer
8::3rr
9::gty
```

Now when I do a grep -f pattern.txt file.txt, I am getting this ->

```
1::anv
2::tyr
3::yui
4::fng
5::gdg
8::3rr
```

The last line in the output above, is causing my problem. How do I modify this grep command so as to get the output (showing correct correspondences) as follows?

```
1::anv
2::tyr
3::yui
4::fng
5::gdg
```

Comment: I tried grep "`more patt.txt`" file.txt | awk -F '::' '{ print $1 " "$2}' But this also gives me the same problem.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Add `^` before your patterns so that `grep` will match a line start with your pattern. If your pattern is actually set of numbers, You don't need a list of patterns. Just use `^[1-5]:`.

Comment: just be aware that ^1 will match 10:, etc. if the numbers ever get that big.

Answer (score 6):

Well, there are lots of possible solutions.  You are telling `grep` to find all lines containing a 3, and the line '8::3rr' does in fact contain a 3.  so you need to be more specific in what you're looking for.

For example, you can change the patterns to '1:', '2:', etc. to match only numbers followed by a colon.  Or you could change them to '^1', '^2', etc. to match only numbers at the beginning of the line.  It depends on your data, but probably you want both, so that your search for '1:' doesn't match '21:' and your search for '^5' doesn't match '53:'.  In which case your patterns file would like like this:

```
^1:
^2:
^3:
^4:
^5:
```