# grep from the beginning of a file (grep -f )

Tags: bash, grep

I use `commands | grep -f - file` to extract piped content from the file.
However I want to extract only if the matching string is in the beginning of the line. Usually I use `grep '^string'`, but it doesn't work with `grep -f`.

```
grep -f '^-' file
grep: ^-: No such file or directory
```

How can I use `grep -f -` and `grep '^'` together?

Comment: Related: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10833105/about-grep-f-match-pattern-with-file

Comment: argument for `-f` is a file containing the pattern (check `man grep` if in doubt)

Comment: `-f` was solution from http://stackoverflow.com/a/437516/1286528 and I like the simple way it works.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`grep -f` is for file containing the patterns.

You cannot call `grep -f '^-'` because it will not take the `'^-'` as pattern, but as file name

If you dont want to use a file, you can use the pipe

`grep -f -`, where the `-` is signal for taking the stdin/pipe and not file.

Here is an example

`echo ^a | grep -f - file.txt` is the same as `grep '^a' file.txt`

Better usage is taking only some patterns from some file and this patterns use for your file

`grep '^PAT' patterns.txt | grep -f - myfile`

This will take all patterns from file patterns.txt starting with PAT and use this patterns from the next grep to search in myfile.

So you can have dictionary in the file patterns.txt and use it for searching in myfile file.

If you have some kind of dictionary (list of strings in file, separated by newlines) and want use this as patterns containing the string in the beginning of the line and you dont have the `^` in the dictionary, you can use sed

`grep '^abc' dict.txt | sed 's/^/^/g' | grep -f - myfile`

So, given the file dict.txt

```
a
abc
abcd
fbdf
```

will first grep take "abc" and "abcd", prefix them with `^`

and call something like `grep -e '^abc' -e '^abcd' myfile`

Note that `^abcd` is a subset of `^abc`. So you would probably have a space (or another delimiter) at the end of your string

`grep '^abc' dict.txt | sed 's/^/^/;s/$/\ /' | grep -f - myfile`